# StackOverflow vs Programmers.StackExchange

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, best-practices, software-engineering-se

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing between Stack Overflow and Programmers Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange)

It seems that both StackOverflow and Programming.StackExchange are both about programming and software development.  I've seen people post duplicates in both camps many times.

Why do we have both?

When is programming.stackexchange (which seems to have noticeably less traffic) the better place to post a question?